# preg_match() not working with post content

Tags: filters

I'm new to Wordpress, and I wrote the following function:

```
function find_my_image() {
if(is_single()) {

    if (preg_match('#(<img.*?>)#', $content, $result)){

        $content .= '<p>Image has been found</p>';

    }
    else{

        $content .= '<p>Sorry, no image here!</p>';

    }


}
echo $content;

}
add_filter('the_content', 'find_my_image');
```

Basically, I just want to find out if my post has a image in it and display proper message.
Currently, I'm always getting the false result, so I'm just wondering what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, $content does not exist. You need to accept the argument into your function:

```
function find_my_image( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $content, $result ) ) {
            $content .= '<p>Image has been found</p>';
        } else {
            $content .= '<p>Sorry, no image here!</p>';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'find_my_image' );
```

Also, note that you should always return the content after your filter - see [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

Comment: But you wouldn't echo it before returning, right?

Comment: @tf That's true, but it looks like this is just proof of concept code anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem remains the same, nothing has changed.

Comment: Are you sure your regex is correct? Answer updated.

Comment: I believe so, I tried it on a regular (non-WP related) file, and it worked fine. 

I tried replacing the $content variable with a random string and regex with that same string, and it works, so I believe that getting $content variable doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: And you are passing content now? `function find_my_image($content) {`

Comment: My answer works fine in a fresh WP install. @tf I've adjusted my answer in accordance with your astute observation.

Comment: @ vancoder, It finally works now, I had my custom plugin installed and it was bugging the whole thing by modifying $content as well. It all works now, thanks a lot :)